# Display null if only one value for Min(Column) and Max(column) SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is my original table

```
ID        value    value1    Value3 
-----------------------------------
  123     45789    null       5648
  234     45789    5468      null
12453      5846    589745    null
21536      5846    null      54689
```

Desired output:

```
ID        value     value1    Value3        ID        value     value1    Value3    
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
  123     45789     null      5648            234     45789     5468        null
12453      5846     589745    null          21536      5846     null    54689
```

Current output with my query

```
ID        value     value1    Value3    ID        value     value1     value3
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  123     45789      5468      5648       234     45789       5468      5648
12453      5846    589745     54689     21536      5846     589745     54689
```

Query:

```
select 
    min(ID) as ID, min(value) as value, min(value1) as value1,
    max(ID) as ID, max(value) as value, max(value1) as value1
from 
    table1
```

Comment: Please explain the logic you want to implement.

Comment: just want to bring into a single line if Value is equal in both the first and second line. value=value, 45789   = 45789

Comment: How are the requirements in the title (min / max) related to your response to Gordon's comment? (You might want to expand your sample data and the expected output for clarification if needed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your expected output from your sample input:

```
select
  T1.ID,
  T1.value,
  T1.value1,
  T1.value3,
  T2.ID,
  T2.value,
  T2.value1,
  T2.value3
from Table1 T1
join Table1 T2
  on T1.value = T2.value
  and T1.ID < T2.ID
;
```

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8d198/2)
You should probably add some aliases to at least one set of columns.

Not sure, though, how you got two rows of data with your sample query.

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.